# How to keep this moving div inside it's parent?

Tags: javascript

I've been making a little game where you have to click the square as it's moving around the page, but now I want to contain it to the parent div (so it doesn't get coördinates outside of the parent).

Can anyone help me with this?

```
var deltaX = 0;
var deltaY = 0;

var div = document.querySelector('#random-move');

function animationframe(timestamp) {
    if (Math.random() > 0.95) {
        deltaX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        deltaY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

        if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
            deltaX *= -1;
        }

        if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
            deltaY *= -1;
        }    
    }

    div.style.top = '' + Math.min(Math.max(parseInt(div.style.top) + deltaY, 0), window.innerHeight - 0) + 'px';
    div.style.left = '' + Math.min(Math.max(parseInt(div.style.left) + deltaX, 0), window.innerWidth - 0) + 'px';

    window.requestAnimationFrame(animationframe);  
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(animationframe);
```

Comment: have you tried making parent position: relative;?

Comment: @Luke I have, but it tries to get out of it, i'd like to have it only stay somewhere in the middle, right now it gets stuck to the sides

Answer (score 0):

You should put the moving div into a container and make your calculations taking in account the max size of the container and the height and width of the moving element. This is a working snippet.

```js
var deltaX = 0;
var deltaY = 0;


function animationframe(timestamp) {
    var div = document.querySelector('#random-move');
    if (Math.random() > 0.95) {
        deltaX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        deltaY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
            deltaX *= -1;
        }

        if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
            deltaY *= -1;
        }
    }

    div.style.top = '' + Math.min(Math.max(parseInt(div.style.top?div.style.top:"0") + deltaY, 0), div.parentNode.clientHeight-div.clientHeight) + 'px';
    div.style.left = '' + Math.min(Math.max(parseInt(div.style.left?div.style.left:"0") + deltaX, 0), div.parentNode.clientWidth -div.clientWidth) +
        'px';

    window.requestAnimationFrame(animationframe);


}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animationframe);
});
```

```css
#random-move {
    background-color: red;
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.container {
    height: 80vh;
    width: 80vw;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div id="random-move"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is get the absolute position boundary's of the container and the object moving around inside.

this can be done through div.getBoundingClientRect();

You then check the current position + the delta to see if it is outside the container..

here is the snippet that is useful for you.

```
//get the bounding rects (left,right,top,bottom) of both the parent and the div
var containerRect = document.getElementById("random-move-container").getBoundingClientRect();
var divRect = div.getBoundingClientRect();

//Using the asbolute positions of left,right,top,bottom of the container and the moving div you can make sure you never move past those coords
//Check the current position plus the delta to check if the new coord is outside... Do this for each axis and edge
if((divRect.left+deltaX) >= containerRect.left)  {
    if((divRect.top+deltaY) >= containerRect.top){
        if((divRect.right+deltaX) <= containerRect.right){
            if((divRect.bottom+deltaY) <= containerRect.bottom){
                //Coords always inside parent div
                    div.style.top = '' + (parseInt(div.style.top, 10) + deltaY) + 'px';
                    div.style.left = '' + (parseInt(div.style.left, 10) + deltaX) + 'px';



            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Here is the overall code: 
https://jsfiddle.net/4e7eby9x/

```js
var div = document.getElementById("random-move");
var deltaX = 0;
var deltaY = 0;
div.style.position = "relative";  

function animationframe(timestamp) {
    

    
  
   if (Math.random() > 0.5) {

     deltaX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
     deltaY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  
      if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
        deltaX *= -1;
      }

      if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
        deltaY *= -1;
      }
    }

    //get the bounding rects (left,right,top,bottom) of both the parent and the div
    var containerRect = document.getElementById("random-move-container").getBoundingClientRect();
    var divRect = div.getBoundingClientRect();
   
    //Using the asbolute positions of left,right,top,bottom of the container and the moving div you can make sure you never move past those coords
    //Check the current position plus the delta to check if the new coord is outside... Do this for each axis and edge
    if((divRect.left+deltaX) >= containerRect.left)  {
        if((divRect.top+deltaY) >= containerRect.top){
            if((divRect.right+deltaX) <= containerRect.right){
                if((divRect.bottom+deltaY) <= containerRect.bottom){
                    //Coords always inside parent div
                        div.style.top = '' + (parseInt(div.style.top, 10) + deltaY) + 'px';
                        div.style.left = '' + (parseInt(div.style.left, 10) + deltaX) + 'px';



                }
            }
        } 
    }

   
         


}

setInterval(function(){
animationframe()
}, 10)
```

```html
<div id="random-move-container" style="width:500px;height:500px;background:#f2f2f2">
<div id="random-move" style="left:0px;top:0px;width:10px;height:10px">test</div>
</div>
```